# What is the verb to express a monkey making a short "whoop" sound?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

What is the verb to express a monkey making a pretty short and complete "**whoop**" sound (often last maybe just 1 second) that sounds like [This sound](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/NUAtH0ycl4A)?

It seems people  say "**howl**" but a howl is normally pretty long is often refereed to a dog or wolf. It may last 5 seconds like [this](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/KqArx-XdAJs)

Comment: I don't think there's a specific verb, but in the context of racist hecklers in football crowds it's usually called ***monkey chanting***

Comment: What's wrong with [**whoop** as a verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whoop)?

Comment: It isn't really clear from the video which sound you mean. There is no "complete" sound, but the gibbon monkey makes a powerful **howl** lasting about a second, and several short **whoops**.

Comment: Perhaps to note, it's pronounced 'hoop', as in '[w]hooping cough' or '[w]hooping crane'. The 'woop' variant I'd consider a back-formation from the spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "whooping". Onomatopoeia is quite generous; you can form words quite freely. If the monkey is making a whoop sound then it is whooping.

For animals that live in the UK or the USA, it is possible that there is a traditional onomatopoeia (the cattle are mooing, for example)  But for specific animals that don't live in the UK, you'll have to be inventive.

Comment: It can also be described as a "monkey hoot" https://stockmusic.net/sound-effects/sound-effect/monkey-hoot/SOU-DCS3450 although that might get confused with owl hoots. Chimps [pant-hoot](https://chimpsnw.org/2011/12/pant-hooting/) when excited.